# When to use this.var and var = ; in a javascript function obj?

Tags: javascript, variables

When I create objects in javascript I find myself setting constants that will not change with `var = 'sjdksjka';` and things that do change relative to the object with `this.x = 0;`.

When is it best to use

```
function a() {
    var b = 0; // var =
      this.c = 0; // this.
}
```

Where and when should I choose one over the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [“var” variables, "this" variables and "global" variables - inside a JavaScript Constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957191/var-variables-this-variables-and-global-variables-inside-a-javascript-c)

Comment: I tried looking for already asked questions!

Answer (score 1):

The first one is in function scope and only visible inside the function itself. The second is bound to the object the function is called on. This case is only useful if the function is a member to the object and you want to modify the object itself. The first variant is used for temporary results during the function call.

Answer (score 1):

`var` sticks the variable inside the function scope. The minute that `a()` finishes executing, the variable `b` will be destroyed.

```
 a()
 console.log(b) //will print "undefined"
```

`this.c` creates an object property. This is when you use `a()` as an object constructor:

```
 d=new a()
 console.log(a.c) //will print 0
 console.log(b)   //will print "undefined"
 console.log(a.b) //will print "undefined"
```

It will also work if you set `a` as a member function of another constructor (via `.prototype.`)